# convert UTF 8 string to URL (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, utf-8

I have a string for example, that may contain special characters (`+`,`=`,`&`, etc...):

```
"Írja ide kérdését, majd üssön entert!"
```

and I would like to convert it to URL accepteble string for XHR like (because IE does not do it automatically):

```
"%C3%8Drja%20ide%20k%C3%A9rd%C3%A9s%C3%A9t,%20majd%20%C3%BCss%C3%B6n%20entert!"
```

Is there any javascript function for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a `+` sign.

To encode this *plus sign* too, use the `encodeURIComponent` function:

```
encodeURIComponent("+Írja ide kérdését, majd üssön entert!");
// => "%2B%C3%8Drja%20ide%20k%C3%A9rd%C3%A9s%C3%A9t%2C%20majd%20%C3%BCss%C3%B6n%20entert!"
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for more informations about the differences between `escape`, `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` functions.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `encodeURI` function:

```
encodeURI("Írja ide kérdését, majd üssön entert!");
// => "%C3%8Drja%20ide%20k%C3%A9rd%C3%A9s%C3%A9t,%20majd%20%C3%BCss%C3%B6n%20entert!"
```

Comment: after receiving is there any conversion required? (in PHP)

Comment: I'm asking it because the + sign does not appear at all after getting data.

Comment: Server-side, you may want to look at the `urldecode` PHP function http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: I have tested and encodeURI does not cover + singn. (but this works: encodeURI(msg).replace("+","%2B")); )

Comment: Check my other answer, that takes your "+" request into account